# python pandas: lookup value in one column conditioned on other column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, match, vlookup

I have the following df:

```
Customer | transaction_id | medium   | first_transaction_flag
ABC        12345            organic      Y                      
ABC        23456            email        0                      
ABC        34567            organic      0                                   
BCD        45678            organic      0                      
BCD        56789            referral     0
```

I need to add a column with the actual first medium. This is the end product I am looking for:

```
Customer | transaction_id | medium   | first_transaction_flag | first_medium
ABC        12345            organic      Y                      organic
ABC        23456            email        0                      organic                
ABC        34567            organic      0                      organic                          
BCD        45678            organic      0                      0           
BCD        56789            referral     0                      0
```

Basically, whatever is the value in the "medium" column for a transaction that has "first_transaction_flag" = Y, copy that value for all transactions for that client in the "first_medium" column.

I think I'm really close to solving it with the help of one of @piSquared previous answer's.

```
df['first_medium'] = df.lookup(df.Customer, df.medium)
```

But not sure how to combine this with a np.where statement for first_transaction_flag =='Y'

So sorry if this was asked before, I couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the first medium in a series indexed by customer:

```
first_medium = df.loc[
    df['first_transaction_flag'] == 'Y',
    ['Customer', 'medium']
].set_index('Customer')['medium']  # makes it a series
```

Then do the lookup:

```
df['first_medium'] = first_medium.loc[df['Customer']].fillna(0).values
```

The last `.values` is necessary so the assignment is not done by index.

Comment: thank you! I am getting a syntax error about the ] in front of .set_index; when I try to add another [ in the front, it tells me "too many values to unpack"

Comment: thank you - the first statement works now; for the second statement I get the ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: argh, forgot to make it a series rather than a dataframe, fixed (and double checked this time, it should work!)

Comment: no problem at all and thank you for taking the time; I still get the value error - my dataset is quite large; is it maybe because the series has only the customers with flag Y and I do have a lot of customers who do not have that flag, since they are returning? So I do have many customers in the index, that do not exist in the series (like customer BCD in the example above)?

Comment: Yes, ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: len (df) 5004770 vs. len(first_medium.loc[df['Customer']]) 5007569

Comment: On the contrary maybe some customers have multiple `Y` flags. Try `first_medium = first_medium[~first_medium.index.duplicated()]`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Oh wow - shocking ... data quality ... thank you so much, this worked!!!!!! You rock